# aligning image to be in the center of the div vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, image, webkit, alignment

it may sounds stupid but i have a problem in aligning images within the div. I have tried to use

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

it works fine on chrome and opera. But it has a bit white space in firefox and safari. For IE the code doesn't seem to work. After that i replace the code with this to make it center.

```
margin: -50% 0 0 -50%;
```

But the image is not vertically aligned in the center. My question is why and how to solve this issue?

Any feedback are welcomed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Center aligning is sometimes tricky when using css to do it as new standards all webpages written using the html5 language must be aligned using css only otherwise it will not be successfully validated as html5. Below i will give you an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zd9z7/

```
  <div class="div1">
  <img src="" alt="" class="image1">
  </div>

 .image1 {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  vertical-align:10%;
  background-color:black;
 }

  .div1 {
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stick position relative on your div and then absolute position your image inside of that. Have your top and left values on the image to be 50% and then margins on the top and left to be minus half the width and the height respectively.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gYLf9/

```
.holder {width:400px; height:400px; background:red; position:relative;}
.img {
    position:absolute; 
    height:100px; 
    width:100px; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%; 
    left:50%; 
    margin:-50px 0px 0px -50px
    }
```

Obviously change your width and height and margins of the image to fit the image size.

Comment: hi @pconnor, I am actually working with percent for the width and height to make it fluid. Do i really need to change to pixel in order to make the alignment correct? My code structure is quite similar like what you have written above. The margin top doesn't work properly because instead of -50%, I have to put -32,8% to make it vertically aligned. Only the horizontal is okay..